# Why isn't Eclipse updating the classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

Since yesterday, Eclipse is not updating the `.class` files of my project.  For example the `filename.java` is up to date, but the `filename.class` file has a modified date of yesterday. It used to work just fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe somehow your "build automaticly" has got unchecked? try to build your calsses with `ctr + B`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Few things I would do or double check:

1. Project > Clean on the project you're working on.
2. Project > Build Automatically - turned on so the code rebuilds in your workspace on saved changes.
3. Window > Preferences and make sure your Installed JRE's and Compilers are matching Java versions

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot for the hints.

Comment: #3 was the cause for me. Updated java version recently.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest doing the following

1. Make sure Java builder is active in the `Project -> Properties -> Builders` menu
2. Clean the project and re-build it.
3. If that doesn't work, remove the `.class` files manually via File Explorer and give it another try.

Answer (score 5):

The steps I followed when I faced this problem were:

1. `Project > Clean` the project.
2. Check the project's properties. Confirm all dependencies (JRE system libraries and Maven dependencies) are in good shape. If not, update the Maven dependencies or check if the build path is configured properly.
3. Check if `Project > Build Automatically` is turned on.
4. Try to run the project; it should properly re-build the project.

Answer (score 4):

> Make sure Java builder is active in the `Project -> Properties -> Builders` menu

Thanks to *@ege-akpinar*, I found out that for some reason the `Java builder` in my project settings had gone missing. Unfortunately you can't simply add the builder again. To fix this you'll have to edit the **`.project`** file in your projects root folder. Make sure the following lines are present in the file:

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

To make the change I closed Eclipse. Afterwards I checked the `Builders` preference, cleaned and built the project again. The change made it work again.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem. And the solution is the Project Java version and JRE System Library.

Follow the bellow steps:

1. Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler [check version of the Java e.g 1.6]
2. Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> JRE System Library [ check version e.g. java-6-oracle]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when the installed JRE and the compiler versions did not match.

It worked when I selected the same version of the JRE as the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have old class files around?  When I added my project to Git, it seems the target directories were different.  I found duplicate class files in two separate folders - one set was old.  Yet, the old set seemed to be the "goto" set for Tomcat.  I discovered and resolved the problem by searching for *.class on the root project folder and deleting all results.  Once I rebuilt the project - it worked perfectly.  (It also fixed my Export to War deployment which also seemed to have been picking up the old class files.)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the build folder of your project, then clean the project (make sure you have the Build Automatically option enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider, open the marker windows. If you have a Java Build Path problem, Eclipse won't update them until you resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (on Eclipse Neon). I had to check the JRE System Library before it would update the classes in the target folder:

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you **add** then **remove** `maven` support to a project.

Eclipse will still be placing the compiled files into `target/classes` & not into `bin` (which you were synchronizing with your `webapps` folder).

To fix this go into **Project Properties** & change:

- *Java Build Path* `=>` *Source* `=>` *Output folder*