# .class file isn't syncing with .java file when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, class, debugging

I might be using the wrong term when talking about "sync" but that's the best way to descrie it I think. I'm trying to debug a project that I've been working on for a couple of days now but for some reason the .java class and the .class file aren't syncing (.class file isn't updating to any of the changes that I make to the .java class that I'm editing). Let me start from the beginning I guess, when I do add break points to my .java file (sometimes the breakpoints are skipped) that I'm debugging and run the debugger when the breakpoint is reached the .class file is opened in instead of the .java file.
[image: .class]

I searched around and found the solution to that with the help of some topics on here, which was "Edit source lookup". So the part about .class opening instead of .java file instead was solved. The main problem now is when I do edit the .java file with anything and run the debugger it completely ignores my changes. For example, if I implement a System.out.println("Test: 1") before a breakpoint or even after it's not printing to the console. Another example is if I comment out a line of code and run the debugger, the debugger still executes that line of code that I just commented out.
I searched for some solutions but they didn't help much. Some things I've tried were but did'n work:
[Why isn't Eclipse updating the classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573416/why-isnt-eclipse-updating-the-classes)

1.) Make sure the Build automatically is checked

2.) Cleaning the project

3.) Refreshing the project, F5

4.) Go to Wwindows->Preferences->General->Workspace and making sure the first 2 checkboxes are checked.

5.) Saving

6.) Restarting ecslipse

If anyone knows how to maybe solve my propblem I will be indebted to you. By the way I'm using java 1.7

Comment: How are you making sure that the code where you put the print statements get executed? Are all the conditions upto the print statement satisfied? Is the method where you have the print statement ever getting called?

Comment: Yes all the body of code within the method is executed and the method is called except the changes that I have made within the method like print statment or commented out code (those are just the few)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe indicates problems in you project definition.
Make sure that your project (main runnable class) specifies correct dependencies - that it does **not** specify dependencies on other jar files but includes dependencies from your related projects

Comment: This could be one of the possible reasons. Another reason could be the fact that the code that the OP expects to get executed is never reached. We could never be sure.

Comment: @ChetanKinger The class is loaded instead of source code - this would mean that Eclipse does not know where source code is...